# collision function not running

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I created 3 balloons(only need 3) and each of them contains a specific word and one of the words is the right answer. I shoot a ball from the cannon and hit the balloons. Assume the balloon 3 holds the balloonText3 which is the right answer, if i hit it the ball and the text disappears. For some reason, the ballCollision(event) doesn't run, i used print statement to confirm it. Whats wrong here?

```
local cannonBalls = display.newGroup()
...

local shot = function(event)
    if(event.phase == 'ended') then

        Runtime:removeEventListener('enterFrame', charge)
        cannon.isVisible = true
        cannon.rotation = 0

        cannonBall = display.newImage('cannon ball.png', 84, 220)
        physics.addBody(cannonBall, {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
        cannonBalls:insert(cannonBall)
        print ('shot')

-- Shoot cannon ball
cannonBall:applyLinearImpulse(3, impulse, cannonBall.x, cannonBall.y )

--Collision listener
print('event listener')
cannonBall:addEventListener ('collision', ballCollision)

    end
end

function ballCollision(event)
   if (event.other.name =='balloon3') then
        scene.updateScore()
        print('Ball is colliding')
        timer.performWithDelay(1, e.target.removeSelf, e.target) 
        timer.performWithDelay(1, e.other.removeSelf,  e.target) 

        balloonText3.isVisible = false 
        audio.play(pop)
    end
end
function scene:createScene(event)
local group = self.view
...

local balloon1 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 60)
local balloon2 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 115)
local balloon3 = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 160)

group:insert(balloon1)
group:insert(balloon2)
group:insert(balloon3)

physics.addBody(balloon1)
physics.addBody(balloon2)
physics.addBody(balloon3)

balloon1.bodyType = 'static'
balloon2.bodyType = 'static'
balloon3.bodyType = 'static'

table.insert(balloons, balloon1)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon2)      
table.insert(balloons, balloon3) 

local balloonText1 = display.newText('\227\129\130', 495, 60)
balloonText1:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
local balloonText2 = display.newText('\227\129\132', 495, 115)
balloonText2:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
local balloonText3 = display.newText('\227\129\134', 495, 160)
balloonText3:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )


group:insert(balloonText1)
group:insert(balloonText2)
group:insert(balloonText3)



end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you put the print statement in the `if` block of `ballCollision`, because I can't see anything else wrong with the listener registration. Also, I don't see anywhere in the code where you set the name attribute of the balloon object. So either

- add `balloon3.name = "balloon3"` (and similarly for 1 and 2) after setting `bodyType`,

or (probably simpler)

- use `if event.other == balloons[3] then ...` in the collision handler. You don't need parentheses around the condition in Lua.

Comment: it gives me an error attempt to index global 'balloonText3' a nil value even though i have it in createScene function group:insert(balloonText3)

Comment: Does it matter if i put it in createScene or outside of it?

Comment: @user3305142 I don't see why it would but this is something you can easily verify yourself.